# Why is opcache_get_status disabled in PLESK by default

Tags: php, plesk, opcache

Can anybody help me to understand, why the `opcache_get_status` is defined as disabled function in PLESK.

```
disable_functions=opcache_get_status;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's for shared hosting security purposes. Because this function disclose information about neighbour user accounts, hostnames and pathnames.